# Chef service not reading from updated systemd unit file

Tags: chef-infra, systemd, chef-recipe

I am using chef template to regenerate redis.server in /etc/systemd/system and reload the daemon, but server is still trying to start service from /usr/lib/systemd/system/redis.service. What am I missing?

```
template '/etc/systemd/system/redis.service' do
  source 'redis.service.erb'
  owner node['myapp']['appid']
  group node['myapp']['group']
  mode node['myapp']['dir_permission']
  notifies :run, 'execute[systemctl daemon-reload]', :immediately
  action :create
end
execute 'systemctl daemon-reload' do
  command 'sudo systemctl daemon-reload'
  action :nothing
end
service 'redis' do
  provider Chef::Provider::Service::Systemd
  supports status: true, reload: true, restart: true
  action [:enable, :start]
end
```

result from: systemctl status redis
[image]

Comment: Are you sure systemd was reloaded? Maybe do you have chef log? Is service is readable?